# Achieved Socratic badge; now missing and not counted

Tags: bug, badges

Under my Biblical Hermeneutics profile, “[Badges](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users/862/simply-a-christian?tab=badges)” section, my Socratic badge is missing, although I finally acquired it today (see the screenshot below).

[image: Socratic badge acquirement]

I currently have four gold badges, but it should be five after acquiring the Socratic badge. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The badge progress tracker is usually quicker to notice that you satisfied the criteria for your next badge. Depending on the type of badge (some are awarded more regularly than others), you'll need to wait 1-24 hours before the script runs which finally awards the badge.

Or, to quote Romans 8:25 (NIV):

> But if we hope for what we do not yet have, we wait for it patiently.